# Skip simplecov summary when there are test failures

Tags: ruby, simplecov

I have a requirement,
Simplecov should print this line

> Coverage report generated ...

only if the test suite is green.

Is this possible?

Here's my initializer

```
SimpleCov.start do
  add_filter "/test/"
  coverage_dir "/tmp/coverage/"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a at_exit hook in SimpleCov where you can skip the message

```
SimpleCov.at_exit do
  SimpleCov.result.format! if all_test_passed
end
```

but could not find a workaround for 'all_test_passed'. Did not find a way to get summary so that i can check if all tests passed.